# Words to describe a video thats not working

Tags: word-usage

The only words I know are “buffer” and “lagging” but are there more words to describe “the video is/has _____”

Comment: There are lots of reasons why a video might not play properly, but to me, any description involving the word ***buffer*** implies that the entire output (video *and* audio) periodically stalls and/or skips part of the material. Whereas ***lagging*** always means one component (either the video *or* the audio) is "behind" the other (it's ***out of sync***).

Answer (score 1):

Why isn't it working? When the reason is known the verb is associated.

- The video is faulty.
- The video has a broken codec.
- The video is broken. (Can work as a matter of fact)
- The video has missing audio.
- The video isn't in the right format.
- The video has some unfixed issue.
- The video is corrupted.
- The video doesn't run.
- The video is damaged.

Besides the traditional ways if you mention streaming video or video files on the net, then there may be various errors, such as:

- The server is down and the video won't load.
- The server is overloaded and it takes a lot of time to buffer the video.
- The connection speed is too low so again the buffering is too slow.
- The video is in a very high resolution that your computer doesn't meet the requirements to play it smoothly.
- The video file is corrupted and it shows mosaic images and plays stuttering audio.
- The video was improperly converted and got damaged.
- The video and audio are out of sync.
- The video player is malfunctioning.

Traditionally we don't say that a video is lagging, mostly the server or the computer is. The website or the video player (on the web) can be malfunctioning too - this sometimes happens on some websites.

Comment: All of your answers are correct for a digital video on your own system, but I feel like OP is talking about *streaming* video as with Netflix, that's not working (because the network is slow, etc.)

Comment: @Andrew Noted your comment into my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about **describing the symptons** of a video that is not playing properly.

> The video is stuttering.

means that the playback is not smooth but skipping frames.

> The video is pixellated.

means that the image has broken into large pixel squares due to faulty decoding.

> The video has stalled.

means that the video won't play beyond a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may seem like the word [**jittery**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jittery) (jitters are shaking movements) is only reserved for situations where we're describing people, it can certainly be used in an informal context to describe a video that has skipping or lagging problems. For example:

> The video is just too **jittery**. I can't watch a movie like this.

[**flickery**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/flickery) and [**jerky**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jerky) are two other similar terms that you might find interesting.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "not working" you are talking about functionality. For it to be buffering, lagging, stalling or almost any -ing verbs I can imagine, it is actually working; just not performing at the level we might want.

Lagging does not necessarily mean one component is out of sync. If you are watching a real time feed, it generally refers to the time delay between the video capture and the display. Jitter will be that the feed isn't coming in smoothly (what buffering tries to avoid).

Now, as to when it, or any technology, isn't "working" it can be given as listed by SovereignSun (with the exception of the broken codec which isn't the video's fault at all). Other possibilities include:

> Microsoft has detected an unknown error
>
> Computers hate Mondays too

and also not to be forgotten the more emotive innumerable variations of:

> The {device/technology} is @!*&*